# z_direction=np.array([0.,0.,-1.])): ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, deep-learning

I run the code in https://github.com/artonson/def

I try to generating synthetic training datasets and I follow the https://github.com/artonson/def/blob/main/docs/synthetic_data.md

When I run

```
cd /code 

export DATA_PATH_CONTAINER=/data  # path to ABC *obj*.7z and *feat*.7z files
export CODE_PATH_CONTAINER=/code  # path to this repo root
export OUTPUT_PATH_CONTAINER=/logs   # path to outputs and logs
export MAKE_DATA_SCRIPT="${CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}/scripts/data_scripts/generate_depthmap_data.py"
export N_TASKS=4  # process this many items in parallel
export CONFIGS_PATH="${CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}/scripts/data_scripts/configs/depthmap_datasets"  # 
export DATASET_PATH="${CONFIGS_PATH}/high_res_whole.json"
export SLICE_START=0  # item ID to start at (inclusive)
export SLICE_END=100  # item ID to stop at (exclusive)
export CHUNK=0  # which chunk to use 
export VERBOSE_ARG="--verbose"  # whether to use verbose logging

python3 ${MAKE_DATA_SCRIPT} \\
    --input-dir ${DATA_PATH_CONTAINER} \\
    --chunk ${CHUNK} \\
    --output-dir ${OUTPUT_PATH_CONTAINER} \\
    --jobs ${N_TASKS} \\
    -n1 ${SLICE_START} \\
    -n2 ${SLICE_END} \\
    --dataset-config ${DATASET_PATH} \\
     ${VERBOSE_ARG}
```

I get error

For test, I change `SLICE_END=100` to `SLICE_END=1`

The logs are

```
08.05.2023 13:49:02.093108  ForkPoolWorker-1 Processing chunk file /data/abc_0000_obj_v00.7z, item 00000002_1ffb81a71e5b402e966b9341_001
{'composite': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.CompositePoseManager'>, 'sphere_to_origin': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.SphereOrientedToWorldOrigin'>, 'sphere_spiral_to_origin': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.SphericalSpiralOrientedToWorldOrigin'>, 'z_rotation': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.ZRotationInCameraFrame'>, 'xy_translation': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.XYTranslationInCameraFrame'>} {'type': 'composite', 'sequences': [{'type': 'sphere_to_origin', 'n_images': 18}]}
{'composite': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.CompositePoseManager'>, 'sphere_to_origin': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.SphereOrientedToWorldOrigin'>, 'sphere_spiral_to_origin': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.SphericalSpiralOrientedToWorldOrigin'>, 'z_rotation': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.ZRotationInCameraFrame'>, 'xy_translation': <class 'sharpf.data.camera_pose_manager.XYTranslationInCameraFrame'>} {'type': 'sphere_to_origin', 'n_images': 18}
{'raycasting': <class 'sharpf.data.imaging.RaycastingImaging'>} {'type': 'raycasting', 'projection': 'ortho', 'resolution_image': 1024, 'resolution_3d': 0.02, 'fov': [115, 85, 80], 'validate_image': True}
{'no_noise': <class 'sharpf.data.noisers.NoNoise'>, 'isotropic_gaussian': <class 'sharpf.data.noisers.IsotropicGaussianNoise'>, 'normals_gaussian': <class 'sharpf.data.noisers.NormalsGaussianNoise'>, 'z_direction': <class 'sharpf.data.noisers.ZDirectionGaussianNoise'>, 'many_noisers': <class 'sharpf.data.noisers.ManyNoise'>} {'type': 'z_direction', 'scale': 0.0}
{'surface_based_aabb': <class 'sharpf.data.annotation.AABBSurfacePatchAnnotator'>} {'type': 'surface_based_aabb', 'distance_upper_bound': 1.0, 'always_check_adjacent_surfaces': True}
08.05.2023 13:49:13.000190  ForkPoolWorker-1 Computing images from pose 0
08.05.2023 13:49:13.000838  ForkPoolWorker-1   getting image
08.05.2023 13:49:13.500857  ForkPoolWorker-1   done
08.05.2023 13:49:13.501472  ForkPoolWorker-1   processing features
08.05.2023 13:49:14.392379  ForkPoolWorker-1   done
08.05.2023 13:49:14.396182  ForkPoolWorker-1 Error processing item 00000002_1ffb81a71e5b402e966b9341_001 from chunk [/data/abc_0000_obj_v00.7z,/data/abc_0000_feat_v00.7z]: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
08.05.2023 13:49:14.399280  ForkPoolWorker-1 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/scripts/data_scripts/generate_depthmap_data.py", line 215, in generate_patches_abc
    for configuration, patch_info in get_annotated_patches(mesh, features, item.item_id, config):
  File "/code/scripts/data_scripts/generate_depthmap_data.py", line 146, in get_annotated_patches
    z_direction=np.array([0.,0.,-1.])):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Why I got this error and how to fix it?